# Using already created core data database in another project

Tags: iphone, ios

I've implemented core data in my project and also able to get the sqlite database created by the app. But, now i want to use this database(created via core data) in another app. I am able to copy the sqlite file to the documents folder of the new app. But not able to relate `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` with the database.

Here is my code:

```
if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil )  return _persistentStoreCoordinator;

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Mall.sqlite"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]];
NSError *error1;
NSURL *defaultDBURL;
if(!success) {
     defaultDBURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MallDB" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
    if (defaultDBURL)
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtURL:defaultDBURL toURL:storeURL error:&error1];
    if (!success)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error1 localizedDescription]);
}

NSError *error = nil;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

Its giving out this error: "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store".

Does anyone know, where I'm wrong?

Comment: This link contains problem relating to changes made in the database but I want to use an existing database(that i have already created from another app using core data) in my current app.

Comment: Fair enough. Are you using the same model file?

Comment: Yes, am using same model file in both apps.